# Cómo puedo hacer para que el usuario le de al botón en un .html de Django, me modifique uno de los valores de la base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, python, django

Tengo estos dos botones que se encuentran en mi .html de Django:

```
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="margin: 1em;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg mx-2" style="width: 150px;">Aceptar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg mx-2" style="width: 150px;">Rechazar</button>
    </div>
```

Lo que quiero, es que cuando el usuario clique sobre el botón, que me cambie un valor, en este caso de una factura de mi base de datos. Es decir, ahora la factura se encuentra en `factura.id_estado=1`; por lo que, si el usuario clicka sobre `Aceptar`, `factura.id_estado` debe cambiar a `2` (`factura.id_estado=2`). Pasa lo mismo cuando el usuario clicke sobre `Rechazar`, `factura.id_estado` cambiará a `3` (`factura.id_estado=3`).

No se si es necesario o no, pero mi base de datos es la base de datos de Django que está alojado en mi Docker.

Comment: Cual sería la duda?

Comment: esa, que como puedo hacer que cuando el usuario clique sobre un botón, cambie de estado/atributo de la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

pienso que debes hacer 2 cosas:
1.- poner un nombre a cada boton de manera que luego lo puedas ver en la view de Django

```
<button type="button" name="aceptar" class="btn btn-success btn-lg mx-2"   style="width: 150px;">Aceptar</button>
<button type="button" name="rechazar" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg mx-2" style="width: 150px;">Rechazar</button>
```

2.- en tu view ahora puedes saber que boton han pulsado:

```
if 'aceptar' in request.POST:
if 'rechazar' in request.POST:
```

luego ya haces las operaciones que necesites segun el boton que hayan pulsado.

Comment: no, asi no es. Aun asi muchas gracias